# Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am working on js validation and want to pass one function into another but i got error "Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined".

My code:

```
validation();
            function validation() {
                var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,10})$/;
                function common_inputs() {
         
                    var inputs = $(' input').toArray();
                    inputs.forEach(function(item) {
                    
                        var element = $(item);
                        if (!element.val() == "") {
                            element.closest('.my__item').removeClass('error');
                            
                        }
                        if ( !reg.test(element.val())) {
                            element.closest('.my__item').addClass('error');                                            
                        }   
                    })
            }             
                
                function inputValidatorClick() {
                        common_inputs()
                        var element = $(item);
                        if (element.val() == "") {
                            element.closest('.my__item').addClass('error');
                            
                        }                                               
                }          
                $('.my-button').click(inputValidatorClick) 
                $(' input').keyup(common_inputs)
                           
              }
        },
```

It seems that there is problem with passing argument "item", but i am new in JS and have no idea how to solve it.
Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: You didn't define `item` inside `inputValidatorClick` function.

Comment: You forget to define `item` in `inputValidatorClick` you can use `event.target` to access clicked item function `inputValidatorClick(event) {var item = event.target}`

Comment: @Tân Yes but i would like to have it in one function - common_inputs. To not copy the same part of code

Comment: @Harshkurra error is not appearing with that solution, but inputValidatorClick function is not working in this case

Answer (score 0):

> i would like to have it in one function - common_inputs. To not copy
> the same part of code

I see that inside your `inputValidatorClick` function, you do something that is already inside `common_inputs` function.

Also, you can remove `validation` which is just used to wrap `common_inputs` function.

```js
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,10})$/;

function common_inputs() {
  $('input').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('.my__item').removeClass('error');
  });

  $('input').filter(function () {
    return this.value === '' || !reg.test(this.value);
  }).each(function () {
    $(this).closest('.my__item').addClass('error');
  });
}

$('.my-button').click(common_inputs);
$('input').keyup(common_inputs)
```

First, we collect all of the `<input>` tags and remove all of the `error` classes from the parents (`my__item`).

Then, we filter the inputs which have invalid values (empty or not match with the regex pattern). From there, We add class `error` to the parents.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, but it will not work for me. I need to use toArray() instead of .each
Is there any way to make callback or something similar from common_inputs to InputValidatorClick?